# vuejs router - this.$route is always empty on refresh

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to set the class `nav-active` to the correct nav element, based from what url you're directly accessing the webapp for the first time.

I have a few routes:

```
export default new Router({
mode: 'history',
routes: [
    {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: () => import('./views/Home.vue')
    },
    {
    path: '/account',
    name: 'account',
    component: () => import('./views/Account.vue')
    }
    ]
});
```

And this is my navigation bar component (NavBar):

```
export default {
    name: 'NavBar',
    components: {
        NavLogo,
        NavItem
    },
    data() {
        return {
            navItems: [
                {           /* root navigation */
                    id: 0,
                    type: 'root',
                    name: 'home',
                    route: '/',
                    active: this.$route.name === 'home' }, 
                {
                    id: 1,
                    type: 'root',
                    name: 'account',
                    route: '/account',
                    active: false
                }

        }
    }
}
```

The state of the `active` boolean inside `navItems` determines whether the navigation element should have the `nav-active` class. I'm trying to use the current route to determine whether `active` should be true or false, by using it this way:

`active: this.$route.name === 'account'`

But once for example I enter this dashboard directly from: `http://localhost:8000/account`
`this.$route`'s items are all empty and the path is always `/`

Help is much appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not tracking `this.$route.name` changes by default with this approach.
Try creating a computed property that resolves to `this.$route.name`, and use this in your data property declaration. In fact, you can just stick the whole thing in a computed property, since you're unlikely to change this.

```
export default {
    name: 'NavBar',
    components: {
        NavLogo,
        NavItem
    },
    computed: {
        routeName(){
           return this.$route.name
        },
        navItems(){
            return [
                {           /* root navigation */
                    id: 0,
                    type: 'root',
                    name: 'home',
                    route: '/',
                    active: this.routeName === 'home' }, 
                {
                    id: 1,
                    type: 'root',
                    name: 'account',
                    route: '/account',
                    active: false
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, both computed and created() properties don't return the correct `this.$route`, do you have any examples?

Comment: I edited the answer! You were missing a closing square bracket there